# How to convert path with coordinates of nodes to <path> tag with points

Tags: javascript, html, position, leaflet, openstreetmap

This my first time programming web application with maps.
I am working with Java servlets, Netbeans IDE, javascript, html and css.
I created algorithm that creates paths from a given Graph (*`osm` file) from [openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org).
*osm file is XML file that represent graph in openstreetmap, more info [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML).

The path structure has list of Nodes where the first node is the source and the last node is the target:

```
public class Way 
{
    private double m_Length;
    private long m_Id;
    //private List<Long> m_NodesRefs;   // this is for  <nd ref=123123> 
    private List<Node> m_Nodes; 
...
}
```

Every Node has Latitude and Longitude:

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>
{

  private long m_Id;
  private List<Edge> m_Adjacencies = new ArrayList<Edge>();
  private double m_Longtitude;
  private double m_Latitude;
  private Node m_Prev; 
  private double m_MinDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  ...
 }
```

Using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) I succeed to show the map but now I want also to be able to show the some of the paths my algorithm found.

This is an example from openstreetmap how I want to show the path:
[image]

I noticed that they are using `<path>` with positions.
I read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp) about `<path>` tag.
I understood that I need to create this tag with content of the positions in order to show the path on the map.
My problem is that I only have the coordinates of each Node and I don't know how to translate it to positions.
For example if I have a path with length of 3:

```
<node id="2500639640" lat="32.1555549" lon="34.8946619"/>/>
<node id="2500639651" lat="32.1556683" lon="34.8946958"/>
<node id="2500639647" lat="32.1557488" lon="34.8947266"/>
```

How can I create from this `<path>` tag with positions ?

**My HTML code (map.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map/leaflet.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map/map.js" ></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyApp</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/map.css" />  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="container">
            <img src="Images/AppLogo.png" class="logo">
            <div id="dataviewer">
                <div id="map">

                </div>   
           </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My javascript code to show the map (map.js)**:

```
var g_Map;
$(function() { //on load

    g_Map = L.map('map').setView([32.0641463, 34.7811246], 13);

    var tilesAttrib = '&copy; <a href="www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors&ensp;<small>Data:ODbL, Map:cc-by-sa</small>';
    // var tilesUrl = 'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'; 
    var tilesUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var tiles = new L.TileLayer(tilesUrl, {attribution: tilesAttrib});
    g_Map.addLayer(tiles);
    scaleControl = new L.Control.Scale({metric: true, imperial: false, });
    scaleControl.addTo(g_Map);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Leaflet's [Polyline](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline), not an SVG path. You'll need to expose your nodes as a JavaScript array (e.g. `nodes`). Then:

```
var latlngs = [];
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
  latlngs.push(L.latLng(nodes[i].lat, nodes[i].lon));
}

var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs);
g_Map.addLayer(polyline);
```

`Polyline` takes geographic coordinates, so there's no need to convert. If you ever do need to do this conversion, see [`Map.latLngToLayerPoint`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-latlngtolayerpoint) and [`IProjection`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#iprojection).